# How to load multiple template parameter files in BICEP

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-nsg

I am trying to deploy multiple parameter files with loadjsoncontext for creation of NSG flow with Traffic Analytics in Azure with BICEP. Below is the template i have used currently to load two parameter files for a BICEP. One with pipeline parameter file to collect the value of Existing NSG and other parameter file I am using as a loadjsoncontext in BICEP instead of the Pipeline variable for the values of networkWatcherName, networkWatcherLocation, storageId, nsgResourceGroupName, workspaceId, workspaceRegion and workspaceResourceId

```
param nsgs array = []
param allowedVNetPrefixes array = []
param logRetentionDays int = 0
param subscriptionId string = subscription().subscriptionId

var nsgFlowLog = json(loadTextContent('./nsgFlowLogParameters/nsgFlowLogCLE_WESTEUROPE.json'))
var networkWatcherName = '${nsgFlowLog.networkWatcherName}'
var location = '${nsgFlowLog.location}'
var storageId = '${nsgFlowLog.storageId}'
var nsgResourceGroupName = '${nsgFlowLog.nsgResourceGroupName}'
var workspaceId = '${nsgFlowLog.workspaceId}'
var workspaceRegion = '${nsgFlowLog.workspaceRegion}'
var workspaceResourceId = '${nsgFlowLog.workspaceResourceId}'

resource flowLog 'Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/flowLogs@2022-01-01' = [for nsg in nsgs: {
    name: '${networkWatcherName}/Microsoft.Network${nsgResourceGroupName}NSG_${replace(nsg.subnet, '/', '_')}'
    location: location
    properties: {
    targetResourceId: '/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${nsgResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/NSG_${replace(nsg.subnet, '/', '_')}'
    storageId: storageId
    enabled: true
    format: {
      type: 'JSON'
      version: 2
    }
    retentionPolicy: {
      days: logRetentionDays
      enabled: true
    }
    flowAnalyticsConfiguration: {
      networkWatcherFlowAnalyticsConfiguration: {
        enabled: true
        workspaceId: workspaceId
        workspaceRegion: workspaceRegion
        workspaceResourceId: workspaceResourceId
      }
    }
}
}]
```

i am trying to test multiple parameter files with loadjsoncontext for each subscription. Each and every subscription i have a NSG resource group which contain the value of Nsgs and storage account. How to use all the parameter files for loadjsoncontext in BICEP?

Comment: What task you have been using for ARM bicep template deployment? Is it via `AzureCLI` or `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment`? Since they should be configured to authenticate access to your tenant via ARM Service connection, what is the service connection authentication scope, the subscription or your tenant Root Management Group?

Comment: Hi Alvin, Iam using ARM Template deployment and Service connection scope is to the Subscription.

Comment: My question is in the path i have multiple files which belong to different subscription and different Resource Groups (individual file for each subscription and resource groups). And i want to load these individual files one by one from a single bicep. We don't want to use the pipeline variable to pass these values. Basically, we want to provide the names of the files in such a way so that we can dynamically call in loadjson. Here iam facing the problem on how i can frame the syntax to pickup the file dynamically in loadjson.